# SQLite querying dates within a relevant range

Tags: android, sqlite, date, sqldatatypes

I am using android studio and SQLite. I set up my prescription_table in SQLite and used type TEXT for my startdate and enddate. I am not too sure if TEXT is the appropriate data type when querying this data. I want to display records where the start date is before or equal to current date and the end date is greater or equal to current date. The below code is from my DatabaseHelper.java class;

```
 //Create prescription table
    public static final String TABLE_PRESCRIPTION = "prescription_table";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION_ID = "PRESCRIPTIONID";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__PATIENTID = COL_PATIENT_PATIENTID;
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__DATE = "DATE";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__DRUGNAME = "DRUGNAME";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__CONCENTRATION = "CONCENTRATION";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__DOSAGE = "DOSAGE";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__PREPARATION = "PREPARATION";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__STARTDATE = "STARTDATE";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__ENDDATE = "ENDDATE";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__DOCTORID = "DOCTORID";

public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db) {
 String prescriptiontable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRESCRIPTION + "(PRESCRIPTIONID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PATIENTID INTEGER, DATE TEXT, DRUGNAME TEXT, CONCENTRATION TEXT, DOSAGE TEXT, PREPARATION TEXT, STARTDATE TEXT, ENDDATE TEXT, DOCTORID INTEGER)";
        //execute SQL statements
        db.execSQL(prescriptiontable);
}

 public Cursor getPrescriptionsPerPatient(String patientid){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        //SQL select statement
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM prescription_table WHERE PATIENTID =? AND strftime('%d/%m/%Y',date('now') BETWEEN " +
                        "STARTDATE AND ENDDATE)",
                new String[]{patientid});
        return data;
    }
```

The error is within the getPrescriptionsPerPatient() Method. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: If you want to compare dates for anything but equality, you need to use a format that can be meaningfully ordered, like the ones accepted by sqlite date and time functions.

Comment: You also need to fix your syntax error.

Comment: @Shawn which syntax error ?

Comment: @Niamh: there is a missing closing parenthese after `date('now')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are storing the dates in [one of the formats supported by SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) (typically: `YYYY-MM-DD`), you can just do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM prescription_table 
WHERE 
    patientid = ? 
    AND date('now') BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```